# #selector on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I'm developing my first iOS app in Swift 2.2 and I have the following problem.
In an utility class, I have the following static method, called by some different `UIViewController`.

```
static func setNavigationControllerStatusBar(myView: UIViewController, title: String, color: CIColor, style: UIBarStyle) {
    let navigation = myView.navigationController!
    navigation.navigationBar.barStyle = style
    navigation.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(CIColor: color)
    navigation.navigationBar.translucent = false
    navigation.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myView.navigationItem.title = title
    
    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"),
                                 style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain ,
                                 target: self, action: #selector("Utils.menuClicked(_:)"))
    
    myView.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
}

func menuClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm trying in some different ways to associate a `#selector` for this button, however I always have the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No quotes.

```
#selector(Utils.menuClicked(_:))
```

`func menuClicked` should be in your view controller class. But if for some reason it isn't, you can do

```
class Utils {
    static let instance = Utils()

    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"),
                                     style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain ,
                                     target: Utils.instance, action: #selector(Utils.menuClicked(_:)))

    @objc func menuClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed quotes and I have no compile erros. However, touching the button, the app crash with the following message `'MyUnimol.Utils' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector +[MyUnimol.Utils menuClicked]`

Comment: @GiovanniGrano Is the menuClicked function in the utility class or the view controller class?

Comment: it is in the same utility class (`Utils`) of the above method

Comment: @GiovanniGrano the sender should be of type `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it gives me the same result. Xcode forced me to put `@objc` in the signature. It is right?

Answer (score 1):

> Swift 2.2 deprecates using strings for selectors and instead introduces new syntax: #selector.
>   Using #selector will check your code at compile time to make sure the method you want to call actually exists. Even better, if the method doesn’t exist, you’ll get a compile error: Xcode will refuse to build your app, thus banishing to oblivion another possible source of bugs.

So remove the double quote for your method in `#selector`. It should work!